# Trouble Iterating Over String Indexes in Python

Tags: python, string, loops

I want Python to take a string and iterate through it, printing several variations with an individual letter capitalized. Like this:

Input:

> "hello world"

Output:

> "Hello world", "hEllo world", "heLlo world", etc.

Here's what I have so far:

```
string = "hello world".lower()
for x in range(0, len(string)):
    new_string = string[:(x-1)].lower() + string[x].capitalize() + string[(x-1):].lower()
    print(new_string)
```

However, this code spits out some pretty funky looking strings:

```
hello worlHd
Ehello world
hLello world
etc.
```

I suspect my issue has something to do with the way I'm indexing the string, but I'm not sure what to change. Any ideas?

Comment: You've got the indexing wrong: `new_string = string[:x].lower() + string[x].upper() + string[x+1:].lower()`

Comment: something like this could work: [print(string[:(x-1)].lower() + string[x-1].capitalize() + string[(x):].lower()) for x in range(1, len(string)+1)]

Comment: What happened when you tried checking the values of the individual slices? (try using `repr` so that you can see quotes around the strings, to highlight empty strings,whitespace etc.)

Comment: I think the wrong code is that  in your first loop  ,the expression :  string[:(x-1)] means  from the zero index ( inclusuve) to the LAST index( exclusive) =  string[ 0 : -1)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple change that should make it work with your syntax.

```py
for i in range(len(string)):
    print(string[:i] + string[i].upper() + string[i+1:])
```

Output:

```
Hello world
hEllo world
heLlo world
helLo world
hellO world
hello world
hello World
hello wOrld
hello woRld
hello worLd
hello worlD
```

There are other methods to do this too, but this one is simple to understand.

PS: You can also add .lower() to the left and right sides. It all depends on the inputs you use.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "hello world".lower()
for x in range(0, len(string)):
    new_string = string[:(x)].lower() + string[x].capitalize()  + string[(x+1):].lower()
    print(new_string)
```

You need to think like index. So if you use `string[(:x-1)]` it will add the capitalized character twice.